# Parallelizing C-Code Module in C++ Program

Tags: c++, c, qt, variables, global

My situation:
I have C code running on a microcontroller. To test this code I have written a test program in C++ that checks the C-functions. Since the test functions are very slow, I wanted to do the whole thing in parallel. However, I don't have much experience.

For example, I have a program module in C that looks like this:

```
/* c-code: */
static int a=0;
void set_a(int value){
    a = value;
}
void inc_a(void){
    a++;
}
int get_a(void){
return a;
}
```

Now I want to parallelize these functions in C++. However, I am bothered by the global variable a, which cannot be avoided in my situation.
In the QT environment I want to perform an "asynchronous run" of the function inc_a. This works but does not improve:

```
int foo(int somevalue){
   set_a(somevalue);
   inc_a();
   return get_a();
}

int myinput = 1,myoutput;
QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run(foo,myinput);
future.waitForFinished();
myoutput = future.result();
```

This is what I want:

```
int myinput1 = 1,myoutput1;
int myinput2 = 8,myoutput2;
QFuture<int> future1 = QtConcurrent::run(foo,myinput1);
QFuture<int> future2 = QtConcurrent::run(foo,myinput2);
future1.waitForFinished();
future2.waitForFinished();
myoutput1 = future1.result();
myoutput2 = future2.result();
```

So my first question is (to be sure): is it correct that the variable a (in C) is now the same in both threads? If not, I have to look over my code again.If yes, how do I solve the problem as elegantly as possible? I thought of creating two C-program modules with the same functionality. However, this makes the program very maintenance-unfriendly:

```
/* c-code: */
static int a1=0;
void set_a1(int value){
    a1 = value;
}
void inc_a1(void){
    a1++;
}
int get_a1(void){
return a1;
}


static int a2=0;
void set_a2(int value){
    a2 = value;
}
void inc_a2(void){
    a2++;
}
int get_a2(void){
return a2;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are out of luck.
Ideally, rewrite your testable asset so that it carries round a state struct containing all those pesky globals, and maybe you will get away with it.

Vroomfondel also suggests that wrapping the offending C code in a namespace might hide the issue, if the code can be made to compile as C++.
You could create as many namespaces as you want parallel threads:

```
 namespace TEST1
 {
    #include "offender.c"
 }
 namespace TEST2
 {
    #include "offender.c"
 }
 RetCode DoTest(int instance, TestId testid)
 {
     switch (instance)
     {
     case 1: return TEST1::DoTest(testid);
     case 2: return TEST2::DoTest(testid);
     }
     return OUT_OF_RANGE;
 }
```

If your target really uses global state and can't be changed, then you could consider using forks.

In a fork, a complete copy of the current state is made for the child to run in, and they both resume with just enough info so you know which is the child and which is the owner. You can also set up a pipe for them to communicate with each other. When a test completes, it transmits its status and exits its forked process.

Forks can be really good for test suites because each fork starts with a completely clean environment.

There is a /lot/ more to getting forking right than I think is reasonable to put as an answer to this question.

The third option is to drive the program externally, so that some monitor script or program launches multiple parallel instances that each run linearly through a subset of the test list. Ideally build in features so the monitor can dispatch tests on demand and load-balance.

Comment: Would a brutal inclusion of the testcode in a number of namespaces be a solution? E.g. `namespace cpu1 { #include "mycode.c" }`. You would at least not be forced to change the test code and with some luck the C++ will produce logically the same code like the C compiler.

Comment: Yes, that is another option, if you can get the code to compile as C++.
You could even wrap your C  module up in a C++ wrapper module file that declares the namespace (perhaps using a command-line macro for the name) and #includes the C file.

Comment: This is the first time I read about "forks" or "monitor scripts". That's why I don't understand exactly what I can do. 
I created a small test project after the example above: https://github.com/mettym/parallel_c_testproject. 
In order for the error to appear, I had to increment several times in the function "inc_a", with a time delay.
I tried to make a brutal inclusion like this: `namespace cpu1 {extern "C"{ #include "c_module.h"} }` and calling the functions with: `cpu1::set_a(somevalue);` Unfortunately, it is not working. How would you do that in this example project?

Comment: You will find lots of information about process forks "out there"
The "monitor scripts" idea is simply that another program, probably written in a scripting language with good threading support, simply launches multiple copies of your actual test program, and monitors and merges their output, so the problem of parallel execution is taken outside your program space.

Comment: These forks look a bit complicated at first glance, but seem to be a powerful tool. Thanks to your example (Gem Taylor) the sample program is now running correctly. Never crossed my mind to include a c-file via #include. It even works with a c-submodule that is only called from the c-modul. I updated the example to GitHub. Unfortunately it doesn't work on my test code, which is of course much more complicated. The functions still seem to have a problem. I still have to go behind that.

Comment: A problem in my code was that the header files (in C) have a `#ifdef HEADER_H`, followed by a `#define HEADER_H` in it. If there are several namespaces, I have to mark all these headers as undefined each time. Especially with library headers, this becomes immediately enormously confusing and unclean. I have to look for another solution. And I will, if I get around to it, take a closer look at the forks.

Comment: You could use several cpp files to include your c code multiple times, but I fear your problem with globals may also be in some of the other c modules?

Comment: If they are standard C headers that you know do not have globals issues, just #include them all before starting the namespaces, and your C test code then won't include them again because of the #ifdef.